# URL with space character render Not Found component

Tags: reactjs, react-router

URLs with a space character in them used to be working fine. They stop working with React Router version 6. Has anyone encountered this issue? How do I go about fixing it?

The URL is dynamically created based on data from a JSON file.

Here is a code sample

```
<Routes>
    <Route path="/working" element={<Working />} />
    <Route path="/an example" element={<Example />} />
    <Route path="*" element={<NotFound />} />
<Routes>
```

Comment: I have spaces because that is how I am pulling the data to generate links. Great news adding %20 works. not if there is a number right after the space

Comment: Spaces in the `path` prop seem to work in the sandbox linked in my answer. I edited it to include a route and link with a number in the middle.

Answer (score 0):

Why have spaces in your route path? I suppose if you must have them you can URL encode them, i.e. `"/an%20example"`.

Example:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <Link to="/an example">an example</Link>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/working" element={<Working />} />
        <Route path={encodeURI("/an example")} element={<Example />} />
        <Route path="*" element={<NotFound />} />
      </Routes>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit url-with-space-character-render-not-found-component]